# Ionic package, how to add onesignal custom icons to the packaged apk

Tags: ionic-framework, package, onesignal

I added custom icons in the right folders (as recommended in the documentation):

```
<project-root>/platforms/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png
```

for OneSignal notifications, but when I build the apk for android using `ionic package`, the icons are not present.

Is there any workaround to add custom icons to the apk produced by `ionic package`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the full path of one of your icon files. Example one of them should be as follows.
`project-root>/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png`

See OneSignal's full documentation below for more details.

[Customize Notification Icons](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons)